# How to group the results of a GROUP BY Query in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by

My SQL Query is:

```
SELECT Comments, COUNT(Comments) [Total] 
FROM Completed_Scrubs 
GROUP BY Comments
```

The result is:

```
Comments    Total
------------------
Cus           202
WEA             1
Process        13
Rework         30
Non           893
Prob            1
App            10
```

I want to add the different rows as:

```
(Cus + WEA) = Uncontrolled
(Process + Rework) = Controlled
(Non+Prob+App) = Business
```

So the result should be:

```
Comments        Total
----------------------
Uncontrolled     203
Controlled        43
Business         904
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: For future improvement - consider adding a table that will map the comment types to the category so you don't have to hard-code the mapping in the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of a `CASE` statement here to define your output and in the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN Comments in ('Cus','WEA') THEN 'Uncontrolled'
      WHEN Comments in ('Process','Rework') THEN 'Controlled'
      WHEN Comments in ('Non','Prob','App') THEN 'Business'
 END) as Comments,
COUNT(Comments) [Total] 
FROM Completed_Scrubs 
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN Comments in ('Cus','WEA') THEN 'Uncontrolled'
              WHEN Comments in ('Process','Rework') THEN 'Controlled'
              WHEN Comments in ('Non','Prob','App') THEN 'Business'
          END)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution, count each type and union the results together:

```
select 'Uncontrolled', count(*)
from Completed_Scrubs where comments in ('Cus', 'WEA')
union all
select 'Controlled', count(*)
from Completed_Scrubs where comments in ('Process', 'Rework')
union all
select 'Business', count(*)
from Completed_Scrubs where comments in ('Non', 'Prob', 'App')
```

Or a little bit more advanced:

```
select status, count(*) from
(select case when comments in ('Cus', 'WEA') then 'Uncontrolled' 
             when comments in ('Process', 'Rework') then 'Controlled' 
             when comments in ('Non', 'Prob', 'App') then 'Business' 
             else 'Invalid' end as status
 from Completed_Scrubs)
group by status
```